# Binning and then combining bins with minimum number of observations?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, binning

Let's say I create some data and then create bins of different sizes:

```
from __future__ import division
x = np.random.rand(1,20)
new, = np.digitize(x,np.arange(1,x.shape[1]+1)/100)
new_series = pd.Series(new)
print(new_series.value_counts())
```

reveals:

```
20 17
16 1
4  1
2  1
dtype: int64
```

I basically want to transform the underlying data, if I set a minimum threshold of at least 2 per bin, so that `new_series.value_counts()` is this:

```
20 17
16 3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: IIUC you could use `groupby` with `filter`:  `df.groupby('some_col').filter(lambda x: len(x) < threshold)`

Comment: Can you provide example output and clarify your input?  Assuming `x` is your data and `new` is your bins, they are non overlapping, `x` is array of decimals and `new` is array of integers.  Is `new` the size of the bin? Is so where are the start boundaries?

Comment: Can you provide a trivial small dataset with data and bins, then hand create the desired output?  Thank will be the clearest way to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt edited OP with an example - does that make sense?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa beat me to it after you posted the data. :) hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```
x = np.random.rand(1,100)
bins = np.arange(1,x.shape[1]+1)/100

new = np.digitize(x,bins)
n = new.copy()[0] # this will hold the the result

threshold = 2

for i in np.unique(n):
    if sum(n == i) <= threshold:
        n[n == i] += 1

n.clip(0, bins.size) # avoid adding beyond the last bin
n = n.reshape(1,-1)
```

This can move counts up multiple times, until a bin is filled sufficiently.

Instead of using `np.digitize`, it might be simpler to use `np.histogram` instead, because it will directly give you the counts, so that we don't need to `sum` ourselves.

Comment: For some reason if I use this on the example above and then look at the value_counts() by changing it into a pd.Series(), it doesn't change anything. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: There's no particular reason for it to be (1,100) - the data is being pulled from a single column of a pandas dataframe

Comment: I'll try your updated answer in just a minute, thanks for the help.

Comment: Meh, I wanted to add the question to the comments, I will delete it from the answer. :D