# Reduce empty bins in python

Tags: python, pandas, bin, binning

I am new to binning in python and I am trying to create bins with property prices. I would like my last bin to be 4000000 + to reduce empty bins.

Here is my code:

```
bins = np.arange(0, 13000000, 1000000)
print(bins)
labels = pd.cut(data['PRICE'], bins, right= True)
labels = labels.value_counts().sort_index()
labels
```

The output is

```
(0, 1000000]            869
(1000000, 2000000]       88
(2000000, 3000000]       20
(3000000, 4000000]        4
(4000000, 5000000]        1
(5000000, 6000000]        1
(6000000, 7000000]        0
(7000000, 8000000]        0
(8000000, 9000000]        0
(9000000, 10000000]       0
(10000000, 11000000]      0
(11000000, 12000000]      1
```

How can I reduce the bins to 4000000 and over to have a frequency of 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binning and then combining bins with minimum number of observations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591000/binning-and-then-combining-bins-with-minimum-number-of-observations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work here, you have to manually set up bin boundaries:

```
bins = [1000000,2000000,3000000,4000000,12000000]
print(bins)
labels = pd.cut(data['PRICE'], bins, right= True)
labels = labels.value_counts().sort_index()
labels
```

Also, have a look here for different answers on that topic:

[Binning column with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-column-with-python-pandas)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem. if it helped you, do you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer? cheers :)